# Ansible won't register variable from shell module

Tags: shell, ansible, sqlplus

I am using `register` in other plays and its working fine. The main issue seems to be when using it with the `shell` module.

here is my current playbook

```
- name: Execute create-auth-key.sql
  shell: echo exit | sqlplus -l {{ data_security_schema_username }}/{{ data_security_schema_password }}@\(DESCRIPTION=\(ADDRESS=\(PROTOCOL=TCP\)\(HOST={{ data_security_schema_hostname }}\)\(PORT={{ data_security_schema_port }}\)\)\(CONNECT_DATA=\(SERVER=dedicated\)\(SERVICE_NAME={{ data_security_schema_service_name }}\)\)\) @/tmp/create-auth-key.sql;
  register: sqlplus-stdout

- name: Set Fact aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  set_fact:
    checking: "{{ sqlplus-stdout.stdout }}"

- name: print aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  debug:
    msg: "{{ checking }}"
```

sqlplus is running the transaction correctly however I want to filter the output of the transaction to grab the generated auth key. To do this I need the output of sqlplus in a var. Here is the error being thrown.

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'sqlplus' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/roles/test.auth-transaction/tasks/create-auth-key-and-obc.yml
```

Why is my `set fact` play failing to recognise `sqlplus-stdout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `-` in python vars..

```
- name: Execute create-auth-key.sql
  shell: echo exit | sqlplus -l {{ data_security_schema_username }}/{{ data_security_schema_password }}@\(DESCRIPTION=\(ADDRESS=\(PROTOCOL=TCP\)\(HOST={{ data_security_schema_hostname }}\)\(PORT={{ data_security_schema_port }}\)\)\(CONNECT_DATA=\(SERVER=dedicated\)\(SERVICE_NAME={{ data_security_schema_service_name }}\)\)\) @/tmp/create-auth-key.sql;
  register: sqlplusstdout

- name: Set Fact aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  set_fact:
    checking: "{{ sqlplusstdout.stdout }}"

- name: print aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  debug:
    msg: "{{ checking }}"
```